# Sync Google Form Spreadsheet with MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-drive

Is there some way to pull the responses from a Google form that is on a Google Spreadsheets into MS Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Publish the Google doc spreadsheet to the web then choose the Microsoft Excel option and copy the URL

In your Excel document and choose Data >> Get External Data >> From Web.

Place the URL link into the Address section and click go.
Leave "Table" selected then choose where to put your data and click "OK"

Click the check box that appears in the upper left of your open Google drive (Excel Dialog Box)
sign in to google and choose your required Share settings.

May take a few seconds/minutes after changes in the Google spreadsheet to be updated to web.

You can use Google Drive and the Docs editors if you have enabled cookies and JavaScript in your browser. You must also have one of the two most recent versions of the following browsers:

•Chrome
•Firefox
•Safari (not supported on Windows)
•Internet Explorer

System requirements and browsers https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2375082?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this. For Google Spreadsheets I would tell Power Query to Get data from a file in CSV format, then enter the Google Docs URL that will return a CSV file.

Google can change their API in the future, but for now here's an example that works:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<KEY>/export?gid=0&format=csv`

Power Query gives you the opportunity to preview and transform the data as required.  Once you have saved your Query, then from the Data Ribbon choose Refresh All to reload the data from Google.

https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Connect-to-an-Excel-or-CSV-file-fc377b2e-a742-4dea-8d7c-8e0f18c8e765